# how can I use an interface entity in RequestFactory's client-side?

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I have some service methods which return entities that are not implemented yet.
For example, I have an interface called IUser and some classes that implemented this interface such as GuestUser and AdminUser.

All entity classes are well-defined already and I want to use their jar files without manipulating them.

My problem is when I wanted to define ProxyFor IUser.class in client-side entity and to call service methods that their return type are IUser. While calling these methods I get the following error: The domain type com.bis.entity.security.GuestUser cannot be sent to the client.

Is there any way to call methods that deal with interfaces in RequestFactory or do I have to change all the service methods to utilize class entitis?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use classes for now. See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5762

Comment: I checked for "public interface GuestUserProxy extends EntityProxy, IUser". It still throws the same exception.

Comment: @user1114455: I didn't mean, that it works *now* (sorry, if it sounded like that). But I hope, that it will, once issue 5762 is implemented! (And yes, I meant to write `extends EntityProxy, IPerson` :-)

Comment: @Thomas: [Rewording my previous comment] Would it then (with issue 5762 implemented) actually be possible to let the proxy implement the same interface it is a proxy for, e.g. `@ProxyFor(IPerson.class) public interface PersonProxy extends EntityProxy, IPerson`? This way, the client and server could work on the same shared code again (which would make RequestFactory much more attractive).

Comment: That's actually exactly what the proposed patch is testing (except with `IPerson extends ValueProxy`). But people are already doing this (implementing an interface in both the proxy and domain object), just with `@ProxyFor` pointing to the domain class.